# Установка Kali-Linux - этап монтирования/чтения падает с ошибкой

Tags: linux, установка

Скачал Kali Linux 64bit для своего ПК, через Rufus создал загрузочную флешку (сама флешка 8Гб). Перезагрузился в бут меню F9 и выбрал загрузку с флешки. В биосе нет раздела Boot, только какие-то непонятные настройки, поэтому заходил в бут меню, ничего не ставил на первое место, а просто запускал USB вообщем. Далее вылез экран установки, выбираю Graphical Install, выбираю язык системы, раскладку клавиатуры, способ переключения раскладки и дальше этап монтирования, вообщем, ошибка. Пишет

> Невозможно считать данные с компакт диска. Убедитесь, что диск вставлен в привод CD-ROM.

Можете обьяснить, что тут вообще происходит, какой CD-ROM, если я выбрал USB и даже запустилась установка, я же до этого этапа дошел, как он вдруг захотел CD-ROM. Почему во всех статьях, во всех видео, этот шаг вообще не комментируется, я даже не понимаю что тут делается, может исо образ ломаный тогда образ не должен был создаться или сам образ я не так создал или проблемы с Legacy/UEFI, хотя у меня в биосе вообще все по другому, я выключаю Legacy, по сути должен читаться UEFI, а сам образ я не знаю Legacy или UEFI, только винда не включается пока не включить Legacy обратно. Помогите идиоту разобраться уже в этой каше-малаше, я уже не вижу смысла, Debian, Ubuntu или Mint - установка одинаково происходит, только исо образы разные. Если это так важно, то я ставлю Kali так как хочу погрузиться в компьютерную безрпасность

Comment: Не, серьёзно, попробуй внутри virtualbox поиграться. Не лезь в реальное железо.

Comment: @don Rumata, ну почему? Реальное железо.. Хочу реальное

Comment: Ну потому что сначала надо потренероваться на кошках и понять как работает установка и разметка линуксовых установщиков. Ты даже определиться с uefi\legacy не можешь, хотя судя по посту у тебя этот самый uefi отключен. И для твоих первоначальных эксперементов виртуалка будет лучше. Потому что когда вычитаешь очередной мануал по ускорению линукса методом `sudo rm -rf /` - то не затрёшь все сови данные.

Comment: @don Rumata, я прекрасно понимаю почти все базовые команды шелла так как тренил на андроиде поставив базибокс, термукс и т.д. даже линукс деплой ставил и в kali потыкал туда сюда

Comment: Ну, судя по тому, что ты создал ещё один вопрос - понимаешь не всё. Ну ок, как хочешь.

Comment: @don Rumata, а у меня виртуальной бокс не работает, какой-то VT-x не поддерживается

Comment: Значит или проц у тебя сильно старый или виртуализация не включена в биосе.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй создать точку монтирования в корень `/mnt`. 
Загружайся с консоли, вписывай: `sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt` 
`sdaX - это твоя флешка`, вернее её раздел, загружайся с `LiveCD`, и вписывай `sudo fdisk -l`. Там ты увидишь все разделы дисков/компакт-дисков/флешек, смотри где у тебя 4/8/16 ГБ, ну сколько ГБ памяти у тебя на флешки столько и будет написано, запоминай значение. И далее уже монтируй `sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt`

Comment: У меня нет консоли, у меня вин10

Comment: @Flippy я тебе написал про LiveCD с флешки

Comment: А, понял. Завтра попробую

Answer (score 1):

1.Скачайте rufus и запишите образ как DD если начнет записывать как ISO то остановите и заново попробуйте. (Мне помогло)
2.Вытащи и втыкни флешку несколько раз

Comment: уже все давно) флешку другую попробовал

Comment: По совету выше помогло, в rufus сделал образ DD, и все пошло, ставил kali на планшет irbis tw92